# cout doesn't work if followed by return (c++)

Tags: c++, return, cout

I'm fairly new to programming in general so I made a program to play around with strings and their limitations, and I came across two questions. I'm confused as to why, when I run the program below, none of the `cout`s in the function are executed, and why the statement `a[0] == b[0]` is true.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string compare(string a, string b){
    if (a[0] == b[0])
        cout<<"a = b"<<endl;
        return "equal";
    if (a[0] < b[0])
        cout<<"a < b"<<endl;
        return "less than";
    if (a[0] > b[0])
        cout<<"a > b"<<endl;
        return "greater than";  

    return "nothing";
}

int main(){
    string a = "Hello";
    string b = "World";
    string str;

    str = compare(a, b);
    cout << "str = " << str;
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
str = equal
```

Comment: You need some braces. This is not Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the behavior you are seeing will become obvious if you correctly indent your code:

```
string compare(string a, string b){
    if (a[0] == b[0])
        cout<<"a = b"<<endl;
    return "equal";
    // ...
}
```

It always returns `"equal"`. You need to add braces to group the two lines:

```
string compare(string a, string b) {
    if (a[0] == b[0])
    {
        cout << "a = b" << endl;
        return "equal";
    }
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is correct result because you have not put your intentional branched codes into the bracket pair `{}`. So in your function, the statement `return "equal";` always gets executed.